# get cookie value in the textbox using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to see cookie value in the textbox.

I have used this

```
document.getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom2')[0].Value=$.cookie('artname',{ path:'/'});
```

but that cookies value is not displaying in the textbox.

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

The "value" attribute is lower-case "v", not "Value".

Answer (score 1):

`value` is case sensitive. Try:

```
document.getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom2')[0].value=$.cookie('artname',{ path:'/'});
```

Comment: @user959128, You're welcome! Welcome to StackOverflow! Once the 10 minute timer is up, click the little check mark next to the answer to mark it as correct. It shows those who take the time to answer your questions that you appreciate their effort.